# SARGable query where parameter is NULL

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2016

I have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc
(
   @Person VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
SELECT updatedBy
FROM   MyTable t
WHERE  updatedBy = @Person AND updatedDate > DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) OR
       @CompletedBy IS NULL
```

The last line (`OR @CompletedBy IS NULL`) ensures that if no parameter is passed, all records will be displayed. However, looking at the execution plan, this is causing a clustered index scan when calling the procedure even when supplying a parameter.

If I take out the OR, the query uses an index seek.

Is there a way I can leave in the catch all behaviour and not cause an index scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an advantage of a stored procedure. You can build two queries, and use an `If` block to decide which one to run.

Alternatively, you could build this as dynamic SQL that only includes the WHERE clause elements you actually need, then use `sp_executesql` to run the result.

Comment: spot on! query running much better!